# About the XML|intent-filter

Tags: android, xml, intentfilter

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.ui05.ACTION_START");             
   intent.addCategory("com.example.ui05.MY_CATEGORY");
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

the relevant `Manifest` is:

```
   <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ui05.ACTION_START" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>  


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.ui05.ACTION_START");                        
      startActivity(intent);
   }
```

the relevent manifest is:

```
   <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ui05.ACTION_START" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>
```

why the first situation would give an `Exception` :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle    
Intent { act=com.example.ui05.ACTION_START cat=[com.example.ui05.MY_CATEGORY] }
```

The second situation is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent filter doesn't include the category for the category you're specifying in the intent. Change your intent filter category specifying `android.intent.category.CATEGORY` to `com.example.ui05.MY_CATEGORY` and it should work.